# динамическая подстановка префикса в урле

Tags: reactjs, url, router

Проект на реакте.
Как динамически подставлять префикс к относительным адресам? Мне нужно вставлять код языка после доменного имени и перед путем. То есть на лету поменять 'http://site.com/page1' на 'http://site.com/ru/page1'. Что-то мне подсказывает, что react-router-dom должно быть что-то подобное, но поиск результатов не дал.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, можно сделать так:

```
//App.js
const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Route path="/some/path" component={Component} />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

//Component.js
const Component = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <Route path={'/ru' + match.url} component={AnotherComponent} />
  </div>
);
```